# RSelenium Server Issue

Tags: r, selenium, amazon-ec2, rselenium

I am trying to use RSelenium, so far I used the below code to initiate the Selenium server on my local computer (on my RStudio IDE) and had no problem.
But I am now working on an AWS EC2 instance on RStudio and the same code does not work anymore so I am a bit puzzled.

> [1] "Connecting to remote server"  Could not open chrome browser.
>   Client error message: Undefined error in httr call.  httr output:
>   Failed to connect to localhost port 4567: Connection refused  Check
>   server log for further details. Warning message: In rsDriver() : Could
>   not determine server status.

```
devtools::install_github("johndharrison/binman")
devtools::install_github("johndharrison/wdman")
devtools::install_github("ropensci/RSelenium")

library(RSelenium)
library(wdman)

rD<- rsDriver()
```

Anyone ? Thanks!